# Is it possible for 'unsupervised learning' model to recognize features on unlabelled images?

Tags: image-recognition, unsupervised-learning

Is it possible for *unsupervised learning* to learn about high-level, class-specific features given only unlabelled images? For example detecting human or animal faces? If so, how?

Comment: This question has been flagged as too broad. You might want to edit the title to ask only if it's possible or useful, not how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming each image contains a single object.

It is possible, however, it is not as easy as you might think. Firstly, you need extract as many features as possible: original image, [LBP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns), [SIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform), [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment#Moment_invariants), contour descriptors to name a few. Than concatenate these features into a single feature vector. After this step, use clustering. You will need a lot of samples to compensate for the number of features. After clustering, use a correlation method to find which features are related to each cluster.

If you need features to classify within a cluster, you could do a second clustering with full set of features and apply the same method. The features that are selected for a cluster will not be suitable to classify within the cluster.